# How to call a function passed in from props

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I have a function being passed in as props in a test. I need to call that function and test it. How do i reference it? Here's some example code.

```
const testFucntion() {
   return "doesn't matter what this does"
}

describe('test', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(SelectEquipment, {
        ...jestVueStack,
        propsData: {
            onSelect: testFunction
        }
    })
})

it('does the thing it's supposed to do. ', () => {
    wrapper.propsData.onSelect()
    expect(wrapper.onSelect).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })

})
```

Wondering how to actually call the `propsData.onSelect` The way I'm doing it there doesn't work.

Comment: It all depends on what library are you using to get `shallowMount`from

Comment: What exactly does 'doesn't work' mean? The function isn't a spy, so it cannot be tested asserted with toHaveBeenCalled. The purpose is also unclear, currently you're testing your own code from beforeEach.